# When using a ThreadPool passing Arc with reference gives a "data escapes the function body" error, passing Arc of data itself works fine

Tags: multithreading, rust, threadpool, reference-counting

I've written some code to break up independent chunks of a computation into pieces and then feed each of the pieces to a thread pool which then does the computation and passes the result back the main thread via a `mpsc`.

The code is as follows:

```
pub fn impute(pbwt_data : Arc<&pbwt::PbwtInfo>, test_sequences : Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {

    let N = test_sequences.len();
    let mut fin_imputed: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![Vec::new();N];
    let safe_pbwt = Arc::new(pbwt_data);

    let (tx,rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(8);
    let mut i = 0;

    for tst_seq in test_sequences.into_iter(){

        let txr = tx.clone();
        let safe_test_seq = Arc::new(tst_seq);
        let refer = Arc::clone(&safe_pbwt);

        let clo = closure!(move txr, move refer, move safe_test_seq, || {
            let val = impute_single(&refer,&safe_test_seq);
            let ret = RowWPos { position: i as u32, row: val};
            txr.send(ret).unwrap();
        });


        pool.execute(clo);
        i += 1;

    }

    drop(tx);
    for recd in rx.iter() {
        fin_imputed[recd.position as usize] = recd.row;
    }

    return fin_imputed;
}
```

The inner `impute_single` function takes a reference to a `PbwtInfo` object and a reference to a `Vec<u8>` object. The inner function does not modify the `PbwtInfo` object in any way, it just reads from it.

Unfortunately when I try to run it this code produces an error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
   --> pbwt_hkhan/src/imputer.rs:138:9
    |
111 | pub fn impute(pbwt_data : Arc<&pbwt::PbwtInfo>, test_sequences : Vec<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
    |               ---------       - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
    |               |
    |               `pbwt_data` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
138 |         pool.execute(clo);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |         |
    |         `pbwt_data` escapes the function body here
    |         argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
error: could not compile `pbwt_hkhan` due to previous error
```

I'm able to fix this error by changing the `pbwt_data : Arc<&pbwt::PbwtInfo>`  in the function signature to `pbwt_data : Arc<pbwt::PbwtInfo>` and creating the `Arc` with the `PbwtInfo` object directly rather than with a reference to it before I feed it to the function. However this means my object is now stuck inside of the Arc and there is further code downstream where I'd like to use the `PbwtInfo` object again.

I could just clone it but it's a pretty big and expensive object to create a copy of so I'd rather not do this. Ideally I'd like a solution where I don't even have to pass an Arc to the `impute` function and can get away with just a `&PbwtInfo` as nothing it or anything it calls ever modifies `pbwt_data`. I know I can do this if instead of splitting off the computation into chunks and using a threadpool I just use a single thread so I feel like it should be possible here.

Comment: Just use `Arc<pbwt::PbwtInfo>` that's already a reference and can be used in most places where a regular reference could. You can then use `try_unwrap()` to get the object back if it's safe to do so.

Comment: Right, but when I create the reference my data gets stuck inside of it:   If I do `let mut am = Arc::new(panel_pbwt);` in my `main` function, now the `panel_pbwt` has been moved to inside the arc and I can't access it directly any more. There doesn't seem to be a `try_unwrap()` method on `Arc<PbwtInfo>`...

Comment: You have to call [`Arc::try_unwrap(your_arc)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap) to avoid name clashes.

Comment: Ty, that worked, I had to use `try_unwrap` as an associated function, so `Arc::<PbwtInfo>::try_unwrap`. Thanks a lot, if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Arc<pbwt::PbwtInfo>` as type.
To retreive the object again you can use `Arc::try_unwrap(your_arc)` which will give the object if there is only 1 strong reference left to it.